# Magento 2.3.x - How can I add fixed tier price for bundle products?

Tags: magento2

It seems that Magento has dropped the customer group price on M2 and now we use a sort of conditional tier price for this. 
I've done this on M1 for customer group but I don't have the level yet to do it on M2.
I would like to allow fixed tier prices for bundle products. ATM only percent discount is allowed. 
[image]

Any help or advise would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: researching this as well. Please update if you find an answer.

Comment: (M2.3 solution) I have wrote my own, it changes the tier price for bundle products per customer groups. it updates directly to database (table `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`)

Comment: @MacA. Can you please provide some reference for this as I am also looking the solution for same?